# CKEditor URL is appended to my working directory

Tags: php, url, encoding, ckeditor, html-entities

I'm using CKEditor for a WYSIWYG experience and I have enabled the ability to create URLs inside it.

When the form gets submitted I use this code before saving the data to the database:

```
$description = htmlentities($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);
```

When I look at the database, I can see that the data is saved like so:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Google&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

To me that seems to be correct and there's no problem with the encoding? Unless of course I'm wrong and that I'm doing something I shouldn't be doing.

Now when I display the data back in a web page I get weird results. I made 2 approaches when displaying the data and each solves one problem but creates a new problem. To illustrate please take a look at my two approaches:

#### First Approach

Since I encoded it using `ENT_QUOTES` before saving into the database it made sense to me to decode it using the same.

```
html_entity_decode($data['description'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

The problem I get with this approach is that characters with accents (`ñå`) don't get displayed correctly. But this solves my issue with the URL being appended to my working directory.

#### Second Approach

```
html_entity_decode(utf8_decode($data['description']), ENT_XML1, "UTF-8");
```

This one fixes my problems with accented characters but it breaks the URLs and instead of opening properly it tries to open something like `http://example.com/my/working/directory/%22http://google.com%22`.

Please note that I'm not that familiar with the concept of character encoding so don't be harsh if I'm doing something that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by combining both solutions:

```
html_entity_decode(utf8_decode($data['description']), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, "UTF-8");
```